# onTouchListener always getting the same MotionEvent ACTION_UP

Tags: android, events, motionevent

At first i always get the ACTION_DOWN mesage so i googled and i found that i have to return TRUE at the end. So i changed it and i started to get always ACTION_UP. I dont understand why.

```
linearLayoutDraggable.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams par = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
                CardView.LayoutParams par = (CardView.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();


                switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                        //par.height = 40;
                        Toast.makeText(MagMainNewActivity.this, "UP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                                par.height=300;
//                                par.topMargin = (int) event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight());
//                                par.leftMargin = (int) event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth() / 2);
//                                v.setLayoutParams(par);

                        break;
                    } //inner case UP
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        Toast.makeText(MagMainNewActivity.this, "DOWN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                                par.height = 115;
//                                //par.width = 60;
//                                v.setLayoutParams(par);
                        break;
                    } //inner case UP
                } //inner switch

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onTouchListener` receive motion gestures, so (while returning true) if you receive a ACTION_DOWN, you will receive each ACTION_MOVE finalized with only ONE ACTION_UP that means the pointer (finger) was removed from the screen at that point.

A click action is represented from a ACTION_DOWN plus a ACTION_UP, while a ACTION_DOWN without a UP is a long press.

Maybe you are seeing just the UP message from the toast since both events are trigged sequentially and the second toast overrided the first one, if you add `Log.v("MMNA", "DOWN")` you can check both at the Logcat

Answer (score 1):

Because before finger is up finger down is first, this means MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN is came frist. It check event action and if finger touch a screen action is MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and it break. Sorry for bad English